# redux form dynamic categories

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

i am using redux form and what i do here is when user selects category the next select field should have all subcategories depending of category selected.

what i did was i created api for fetching all categories, i trigger action via componentWillMount and load all categories in first categories select field, then i use formValueSelector of redux-form to get selected category to the state/this.props, then i use componentWillReceiveProps() to trigger fetching subcategories with that e.g. "this.props.categoryId" that i put to state with formValueSelector and that works.

and my question is, is this the right aporoach, is there a better way?
and the second question, is how do i reset categoryChildId field to, lets say blank when the categoryId field is changed?

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import {CopyToClipboard} from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';
import * as actions from '../../actions/category';

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    {touched &&
     error &&
     <div className="error">{error}</div>}
  </div>
)

const renderTextArea = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <textarea {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    {touched &&
     error &&
     <div className="error">{error}</div>}
  </div>
)

class AddProduct extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: `${process.env.SITE_URL}/user/${props.user.username}`,
      copied: false,
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
     this.props.startSetCategories()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.props.startSetCategoryChildren(nextProps.categoryId)
      console.log(nextProps)
  }

  renderCategorySelector = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <select {...input}>
          <option value="">select category</option>
          {!this.props.categories ? (
            <option value="">loading...</option>
          ) : (
            this.props.categories.map(category => <option value={category._id} key={category._id}>{category.name}</option>)
          )
        }
        </select>
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderCategoryChildSelector = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <select {...input}>
          <option value="">select sub category</option>
          {!this.props.categoryChildren ? (
            <option value="">loading...</option>
          ) : (
            this.props.categoryChildren.categoryChildren.map(categoryChild => <option value={categoryChild._id} key={categoryChild._id}>{categoryChild.name}</option>)
          )
          }
        </select>
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    )
  }

  submitForm = values => {
    console.log(values)

  }

  render() {
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, categoryId } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="profile-wrapper">
        <div className="profile">
          <form className="profile-addproduct-left" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submitForm.bind(this))}>
            <div className="profile-addproduct-title">
              <h2>New Product</h2>
              <p>Fill out the form.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="profile-form-group">
              <div className="profile-form-item">
                <p>Title</p>
                <Field
                  name="title"
                  type="text"
                  label="title of a product"
                  component={renderField}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="profile-form-item">
                <p>Category</p>
                <Field
                  name="categoryId"
                  type="text"
                  component={this.renderCategorySelector}
                  label="category"
                />
                {this.props.categoryId ?
                  <Field
                    name="categoryChildId"
                    type="text"
                    component={this.renderCategoryChildSelector}
                    label="categoryChild"
                  /> :
                  ''
                }
              </div>


              <div className="profile-form-item">
                <p>Description</p>
                <Field
                  name="description"
                  type="text"
                  label="Write some interesting..."
                  component={renderTextArea}
                />
              </div>


            </div>
            <div className="profile-addproduct-form-submit">
              <button className="button button--register" type="submit" disabled={this.state.isLoading || pristine}>Submit New Product</button>
            </div>
          </form>


        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};


AddProduct =  reduxForm({
  form: 'addproduct-form'
})(AddProduct)

const selector = formValueSelector('addproduct-form')

AddProduct = connect(state => {
  const categoryId = selector(state, 'categoryId')
  return {
    categoryId,
    categories: state.category.categories,
    categoryChildren: state.category.categoryChildren
  }
}, actions)(AddProduct)

export default AddProduct
```

Comment: I think it's a reasonable approach. If you want to delete the field, you can just do `this.props.change('categoryId', null)`

Comment: thank you for your feedback and help, i've managed the reset field problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call the `startSetCategoryChildren` (or any other api) in `componentWillReceiveProps`... because it would call every time whenever componentWillReceiveProps called

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.props.startSetCategoryChildren(nextProps.categoryId)
  console.log(nextProps)
}
```

Instead of this you can to do this on `handleChange` of the `Field`

```
            <Field
              name="categoryId"
              type="text"
              component={this.renderCategorySelector}
              label="category"
              onChange={(e) => this.props.startSetCategoryChildren(e.target.value)}
            />
```

Comment: Wow thanks, idk how i didnt think of this.:D definitely a better solution

Comment: If this solution is correct, mark as correct for future references.